# I tried ctrl + x to save and I can't save it the way I used to in git

Tags: git

I am pretty new to this stuff and I am a little confused rn. When I first started to learn git a week ago, things were smooth. When I typed vim 'file name' this screen would show up and everything was clear. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxMWm.jpg)

But when I opened it today and tried to edit a file, and save it with ctrl + x, this screen shows up [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxmOR.jpg)

I don't know why this happens, and I hope you can help me understand things a little clearer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those are just text editors. It's not to do with git. First one is nano, which you exit with ctrl x. Second one vim that you can exit :q or :q! to discard and exit or :wq to save and quit.

if you just type `nano` in bash or `vim` it will open them.

For git if you just want to add message can do git commit -m "this is my commit message" and then it's no editor.

You can just look up different commands for nano and vim if you want to use them. If you want to set a specific editor for git something like git config --global core.editor "nano" will set nano

Hope it helps

Comment: That makes sense. I assumed git bash will use nano all the time as I set it in the very beginning. And I didn't know how normal git looked like so I confused. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @masphael if this answer solved your problem, you can accept it as the answer.